# Regex replace first two letters within column in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1
A_element_1_+_none 
C_BLOCA_element 
D_element_3
element_'
BasaA_bloc
B_basA_bloc
BbasA_bloc
```

and I would like to remove the first `2 letters` within each row of `COL1` only if they are within that list :

```
the_list =['A_','B_','C_','D_']
```

Then I should get the following output:

```
COL1
element_1_+_none 
BLOCA_element 
element_3
element_'
BasaA_bloc
basA_bloc
BbasA_bloc
```

So far I tried the following :

```
df['COL1']=df['COL1'].str.replace("A_","")
df['COL1']=df['COL1'].str.replace("B_","")
df['COL1']=df['COL1'].str.replace("C_","")
df['COL1']=df['COL1'].str.replace("D_","")
```

But it also remove the pattern such as in row2 `A_` and does not remove only the first 2 letters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values to replace in `the_list` always have that format, you could also consider using str.replace  with a simple pattern matching an uppercase char A-D followed by an underscore at the start of the string `^[A-D]_`

```
import pandas as pd

strings = [
    "A_element_1_+_none ",
    "C_BLOCA_element ",
    "D_element_3",
    "element_'",
    "BasaA_bloc",
    "B_basA_bloc",
    "BbasA_bloc"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["COL1"])
df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].str.replace(r"^[A-D]_", "")

print(df)
```

Output

```
                COL1
0  element_1_+_none 
1     BLOCA_element 
2          element_3
3          element_'
4         BasaA_bloc
5          basA_bloc
6         BbasA_bloc
```

Comment: In her case, since the letters in the list are from A to D so it would be: `df['COL1'].str.replace(r"^[A-D]_", "")`

Comment: @alphaBetaGamma I read it again, and thought the same thing :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `apply()` function from pandas. So if the string is with the concerned patterns, we ommit the two first caracters else return the whole string.

```
d["COL1"] = d["COL1"].apply(lambda x: x[2:] if x.startswith(("A_","B_","C_","D_")) else x)
```